# notification disable when move on other activity in android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have to develop an one push notification application.

i did like :

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("offer");
     displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
   if(Constants.response != null){
    generateNotification(context,message);
  }
       }


  private static void generateNotification(Context context,String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyDealProducts.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      
}
```

here the notification is generated successfully on logged in customer.

Now  didn't visit these notification at the same time logged out the customer form which means i don't need to enable the notification.

But here the notification is enabled.How can i disable the notification after logged out the customer ???

please give me a suggestions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can cancel the Notification that you have generated, whenever the user is logged out.

Use the method `cancel(int id)` (Where id is the notification id, in your case, its `0`) or `cancelAll()` of `NotificationManager`.